# What is the drupal way for wysiwyg reply edit box?

Tags: drupal, forum, editbox

I'm making a forum and I'm using drupal6 advance-forum module.

I browsed all the admin sections and I still cannot figure it out
how to put a wysiwyg edit toolbar on the reply form.
It shows in the admin section when I create a topic but not outside the
admin section.

Should I do that manually? - I can do it with java script, but if I
do that, than I don't think that it will be the drupal easy maintain way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6, I'd use the WYSIWYG Module along with the Better Formats Module.

http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg
http://drupal.org/project/better_formats

After installing and enabling both of these modules you'll want to:

1. Add and/or configure a specific input format for wysiwyg use on comments at ***Administer > Site Configuration > Input Formats*** (might want to disable any filters at first to avoid possible conflicts with the WYSIWYG script)
2. From the Input Formats admin section, click on the ***Defaults*** tab and select this input format as the default for comments.
3. Finally, visit ***Administer > Site Configuration > WYSIWYG*** where you can get instructions on installing your WYSIWYG of your choice.  After the WYSIWYG scripts are in place you can select that WYSIWYG for your chosen input format and configure any available options.

Better Formats also allows you to turn on default input formats per node type, so you could use the same WYSIWYG enabled input format as the default for initial forums posts as well as the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Wysiwyg editors in Drupal us usually related to input formats. Check what input format is used for the reply form.

The [wysiwyg module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and [better formats module](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) is pretty good combo you can use to setup editors for different roles in different senarios.